# Write file in home directory when running `npm install`

Tags: json, node.js, ubuntu, permissions, npm

When install a `foo` module, as developer, I want to write `~/.foo.json` file (where `~/` is the user's home directory).

For this I did in `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
     "preinstall": "./installation/preinstall.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

And in `/installation/preinstall.js` (that is executable), I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Dependencies
var Fs = require("fs");

function getUserHome() {
    return process.env[(process.platform == 'win32') ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME'];
}

console.log("Creating configuration file ...")
Fs.writeFileSync(getUserHome() + "/" + ".foo.json", JSON.stringify(
    require("./sample-config"), null, 4
));
```

When running `sudo npm install ...@... -g` I get the following output:

```
ionicabizau@laptop:~$ sudo npm install ...@...-alpha1 -g                           
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/...
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/...

> ...@...-alpha1 preinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/...
> ./installation/preinstall.js

Creating configuration file ...

fs.js:432
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/ionicabizau/.foo.json'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:971:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/.../installation/preinstall.js:11:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Why `EACCESS` error, even if I run it with `sudo`?

Running Ubuntu 14.04, if it's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html#user), *If npm was invoked with root privileges, then it will change the uid to the `user` account or uid specified by the user config, which defaults to `nobody`. Set the `unsafe-perm` flag to run scripts with root privileges.*

So, that's the problem here. The environment variables `HOME` or `USERPROFILE` remain the same, but the user is `nobody`.

However, `--unsafe-perm` prevents this:

```
sudo npm install foo -g --unsafe-perm
```